# Using XA transaction from stored procedure in db2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, xa

I am looking for a simple way of using xa transactions from DB2 stored procedure.

I have found many links and articles using JDBC and XAConnection in DB2, but what I am looking for is use of XA transactions from a procedure stored in the DB2 database. Nothing java, only I couldn't manage to find any valuable resource.

I have only found this [page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/c0005107.htm), but I could manage to get any further.

Many many thanks for your answers,

Kim

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work. XA requires an external transaction manager.